# How to avoid that AJAX jump when at the bottom of a web page

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

**Situation:**

1. User is scrolled down to the very bottom of a web page ( *page is larger than window height*. )
2. Ajax content is loaded which causes the total height of the web page to increase

**Result:**

- Page jumps slightly to adjust for the longer content, making it uncomfortable for the user to find the spot they were looking at.

It seems that for a split second as the AJAX loads, there is no content, causing the page to jump up slightly. Then the content loads causing this bumpy look.

**Solution?**

Do you have a go-to solution you use for solving this problem? Perhaps using # links or window/document height?  What is your recommended solution?

Comment: position:relative;
 height:100%;
 overflow: scroll;   is that enough? is der any need of ajax?

Comment: Give a fixed height...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do in many ways. My favourite one is using `min-height` or fixed `height` and `overflow: auto;`:

```js
$(function () {
  $("button").click(function () {
    $("#ajax p").fadeOut(function () {
      $(this).delay(1000).fadeIn();
    });
  });
});
```

```css
* {font-family: 'Segoe UI'}
#ajax {min-height: 225px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<h1>Some Filler</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex ipsum nobis qui! Laudantium, ex! Ea dolorum eos quibusdam, non sapiente eligendi. Officia illum provident, quisquam doloribus, nostrum perferendis voluptatem blanditiis.</p>
<p>Porro totam assumenda sint ratione consequatur temporibus doloremque expedita dolores excepturi, dolore eveniet magni, accusamus cumque explicabo nemo modi, voluptatum architecto fugiat esse obcaecati voluptatem veniam cupiditate officiis? Iusto, pariatur.</p>
<p>Beatae necessitatibus dolor earum minima adipisci velit impedit dolores porro doloribus quod. Excepturi veritatis maxime illum voluptate facilis esse, dolorum omnis aliquam accusantium ratione nihil inventore, sit, voluptas. Aut, optio.</p>
<p>Cupiditate itaque odio dolore quaerat optio voluptate natus esse reiciendis quo laboriosam harum mollitia facilis dignissimos ullam voluptatum consequatur eveniet, veritatis architecto. Suscipit labore, unde earum soluta esse fuga perferendis.</p>
<p>Repudiandae alias reiciendis itaque, atque incidunt ipsum quas voluptate. Fugiat dolorem nam recusandae aspernatur aperiam, nihil iure laudantium sequi ut id veniam, placeat quasi itaque facere eum cum, ratione deleniti.</p>
<p>Consequatur assumenda quas ratione voluptates nobis nihil quasi illum voluptas, alias repellendus fugit harum sunt pariatur vel error laborum repudiandae, a sint, facere maiores modi libero illo ipsum. Quas, quidem.</p>
<p>Facilis provident ea beatae dolor ratione vero explicabo ut consequuntur eveniet, omnis facere quis ducimus, voluptatum repellat corrupti numquam esse voluptas maiores culpa voluptates optio quo nam accusamus, eos! Nemo!</p>
<p>Corporis, quidem voluptas. Provident et, quia dignissimos, enim recusandae ipsa earum doloribus, voluptate maxime temporibus ex nihil. Maiores, rem itaque, porro rerum quam, est accusantium beatae distinctio numquam pariatur quo.</p>
<p>Velit doloremque saepe dicta dolor ipsam vero deleniti hic enim minima modi voluptatibus quasi adipisci dolores, pariatur quidem asperiores laudantium suscipit obcaecati nulla amet libero unde omnis nobis excepturi. Sit.</p>
<p>Consectetur voluptas, dignissimos. Saepe numquam aliquid vel tenetur, iure, atque voluptas nostrum aut incidunt provident magnam blanditiis sint deleniti reiciendis, sed eos dicta sit rerum quas enim necessitatibus optio quibusdam.</p>
<button>Trigger AJAX</button>
<div id="ajax">
  <p><strong>Thsi is the AJAX Triggerer</strong>. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. At quasi eveniet iure eius accusamus eaque labore voluptates! Eaque, repellendus consectetur quam exercitationem culpa reprehenderit recusandae, consequuntur pariatur sunt, soluta dolore.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Praveen. Thanks for taking the time to create a very thorough response. It seems that your code is still creating a page jump.  I ran your code in full screen and shrank my browser size so that the content extends the browser height, then scrolled to the bottom and pushed your button. The page jumps a little as the new content is loaded.

Comment: To prevent the skip, include an `overflow` of some kind: https://jsfiddle.net/d0kdk98t/

Comment: @Praveen, I played around with this answer, and it makes a lot of sense.  Thank you. If I add a min-height to the div in which the content is swapping, the jump disappears.  However, since this is a responsive site, the height constantly changes based upon the width of the screen.  Do you have any recommendations for this? What comes to my mind is running a JS command to grab the current div height and set the css based on that each time the button is pressed.

Comment: @LuckyInJapan Exactly. I was about to tell you that. You can do that too.

Comment: @Praveen, gotcha.  I will add the JS bit in an answer, then check yours off.  Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

**For Responsive Design:**

To add upon Praveen's answer, there is one extra step needed for responsive design where the height of the div will change.  In this case, creating a min-height is not enough and sometimes may break design.

When the button is pressed, run a jQuery function to grab the current height of the div where AJAX will replace the content. Then set the min-height to that value. For example:

```
$('button').click(function () {
    var num = $( '.ajaxDiv' ).height;
    $( '.ajaxDiv' ).css( 'minHeight' , num );
});
```